# How to align Imageview and description using textviews as shown in the picture

Tags: java, android-layout

Could you please help me  to place an `ImageView` and also 'Description' having Headline1 and text, Headline2 and some text.

I tried to do but I am not able to do exactly as shown in the picture:

[image: my_picture]

If the description is more, need to have a scroll bar. It should work for all the screen sizes. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_inner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_inner_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/image1" />

            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/UpdateTimeText"
        android:text="is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
            
           
            
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>


flag
```

I tried adding customized title bar with button but that's breaking my UI. So I would want to place a footer in my UI itself which is outside the scroll bar
with 2 buttons back and next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/directory_icon" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_inner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="HeadLine 1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." />

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="HeadLine 2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." />
        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutButtons"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="previous"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="next"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's your footer ?  What do you except ?

Comment: I want to add a footer bar with two buttons on it. Back and Next Button

Comment: Inside or outside scroll ?

Comment: I tried adding customized title bar with button but that's breaking my UI. So I would want to place a footer in my UI itself which is outside the scroll bar.

Comment: @user6453421, I update answer, next time, please accept answer if it's useful

Comment: Its working perfectly. Thank you Laurent. Where should I accept the answer? I am new to stackoverflow. Please let me know where to accept it and I shall do it.